# Callback function of javascript not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, xml, vb.net, jscript

Callback function is not working in IE11. Function _onReadyStateChange() takes two parameters. But when this function is called parameters sender and xmlHttp is assigned as 'Undefined' variables.

```
 this.xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
debugger
this._onReceiveHandler = Function.createCallback(this._onReadyStateChange,
    {
        sender: this,
        xmlHttp: this.xmlHttpRequest
    });
this._started = true;
this.xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = this._onReceiveHandler;
this.xmlHttpRequest.open(verb, webRequest.getResolvedUrl(), false); // False to call Synchronously
```

Calling of callback function _onReadyStateChange()

```
 _onReadyStateChange: function (e)
    {
        debugger

       if (e.xmlHttp.readyState === 4)  
        {
            ------
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Function.createCallback`? It's not a part of the native JS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd409287(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: That documentation seems to be related to Visual Studio, you're running this in a browser?

Comment: yes running this function in a browser

Comment: Any alternative for this function???